# Update user email address in meteor

Tags: meteor, angular2-meteor

I want to update email address in meteor by :

```
Meteor.users.update(this._id, {$set: {"emails[0].address": "deleted_" + preEmail }});
```

but instead of updating email array, 0 argument, then address ,it create a new field like emails[0] then address.
it is interesting that in one other .js file it works correctly!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were almost there. In you code change "`emails[0].address`" with `emails.0.address` . My code is working in Angular 2 meteor. I hope it will work for you also :)

```
 Meteor.users.update({
        _id: id
     }, 
     {
        $set: {
            'emails.0.address': address,
            "username": username
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

The Accounts package comes with pre-built functions for changing the email address.

```
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base'

//get old email
const oldEmail = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).emails[0].address;

//add new email
Accounts.addEmail(this.userId, args.email);

//remove old email
Accounts.removeEmail(this.userId, oldEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could setup the array first and then update emails like this

```js
var newEmail = [{address:email, verified: false}]
Meteor.users.update({_id:this._id}, {$set: {emails:newEmail }});
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the issue is that your filter is wrong.

```
Meteor.users.update({_id:this._id}, {$set: {"emails[0].address": "deleted_" + preEmail }});
```